Applescript no longer attaches file to email
I have an Applescript that until recently worked fine in generating and sending a plain text email, and in attaching a jpg file (about 119 KB). Since upgrading my system to Mac OS Sonoma 14.4.1, the attach command no longer does anything. I've scoured the Web for solutions, but have found no solution so far. Does anyone know anything about such a glitch?
I have looked for alternate ways for Applescript to add an attachment to an email. I've put extra delay time (many seconds) both before and after the attach command. And I've been working with a script that is whittled down to a bare skeleton for sending an email. No luck.
Here is a copy of my skeleton script:
set fileName to "<path to my file>" // Actual file path inserted between quotes

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set mymail to make new outgoing message at the beginning of outgoing messages with properties {subject:"A Test"}
    tell mymail
        make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:"<my email address>"} // Again, my email address (for testing) inserted between quotes
        delay 1 // I've tried as much as 16 seconds
        set content to "This is a test."
    end tell
    
    set visible of mymail to true
    
    tell mymail to make new attachment with properties {file name:fileName} at after last paragraph
    
    delay 1 // I've also tried up to 16 seconds here
    activate
    send mymail
end tell

Applescript creates and sends the email perfectly well. And I've found that it does indeed find the file (via display dialog commands). And before upgrading to the most recent version of Sonoma, it attached the jpg file; but now it just sends the email with no attachment. I'd greatly appreciate any ideas!

Well, until you find a solution, consider going back to the previous system if the task needs completing - that gives you chance to solve it.

Is fileName in fact a string?  There’s a possible explanation for what’s happening, but you would have had to upgrade from a really old version of macOS for it to have been working before.

Actually, I defined "fileName" in the very first line of code — it's the path to the file that I want to attach to an email. I'm not sure what explanation you'd be referring to, Chris, but the upgrade I just made was from a slightly earlier version of Mac OS 14 (14.3.1 maybe, I forget), to OS 14.4.1.
I have found a workaround: Simply insert the file as part of an email signature; set the sender's email to default to that signature; then send desired email(s). Afterwards, revert to normal signature after email with attachment is sent (mass mailing, in my case).

That’s a creative solution — I didn’t know you even could put a file attachment in a signature.

The issue I found running your script is that fileName — which you’re passing to Mail in {file name:fileName} — is a plain string, and for sandboxing reasons, that doesn’t work.  Mail fails (unfortunately silently) to be able to read the file, and you get no attachment.
The solution is to pass a file specifier to Mail — when you do that, the system knows that it should pass a sandbox extension for that file along with the “make” command.  Depending on the format of the path string, it should be either set fileName to alias "..." (for classic Mac OS colon-delimited paths) or set fileName to POSIX file "..." (for UNIX-style slash-delimited paths).
I’m mystified why it worked before — Mail has been sandboxed for quite a few releases — unless somehow you had already used that same file in Mail before running your script.

Thanks, Chris! The alias and the POSIX options both worked. I don't know why it worked in the older OS version without the alias or POSIX unless, as you say, it was because I had already used that file beforehand in Mail (which I had).
And yes, a file can be dragged into a signature in Mail, effectively making it part of the signature — but it also appears as an attachment to the mail that can be opened. No longer necessary now, though!
